# PHP login - detect user type with SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

Basically what Im trying to do is create a login system where there are two different types of user. Each user has an ID, username, passcode and role. The role determines whether they are a  lecturer or student(which overall will determine the view that is given). I have the login working generically where a user can login and reach a page called welcome.php. When a lecturer logs in I need an include file /lecturer.php to open and when a student logs in a file named /student.php to open. Below is my code:

//TABLE//

```
CREATE TABLE `admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `passcode` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

//PHP//

```
<?php

include("config.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from form 

$myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']); 
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']); 


$sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$myusername' and passcode='$mypassword'";


$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
    {
        session_register("myusername");
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;

        header("location: welcome.php");
    }
    else 
        {
        $error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
}
?>
```

THANKS in advance for any help

Comment: Why are you using archaic code?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). `addslashes` is not a valid escaping method and `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). See: [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Answer (score 2):

**First of all - please don't use mysql_* functions anymore - they are oficially deprecated - look at the red box on php.net site**

The alternatives you can use is **mysqli** or **PDO**, they are very similar, they even both have procedural calls if you feel more comfortable with them, although i recommend the objective approach.

**Second of all** - use proper esacping. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php  for information about prepared statements which prevents the SQL injection that you're vulnerable to. (for PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

**Third of all** - the solution to your problem, add the "role" column to your statement and an additional if presented below

```
if($row["role"] == "lecturer") {
    include_once('lecturer.php');
} else {
    include_once('student.php');
}
```

Comment: I like your answer more :)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, the links are very useful. Where do i place the if($row["role"] == "lecturer") {
    include_once('lecturer.php');
} else {
    include_once('student.php');
}  -- As it still redirects to welcome.php

Answer (score 1):

Just add `role` to teh columns you are selecting:

```
$sql="SELECT id, role FROM admin WHERE username='$myusername' and passcode='$mypassword'";
```

And then grab the field value and trigger appropriate logic based on value.